# Transform alert to console.log

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change the `alert()` function to log the message instead of showing up a popup?

Some outside team members does like the use the alert function, but we don't want it because they aren't removing them.

So I want to add some code in our angular application that logs the message in the console instead of popping up.
So, I want some code which don't require to change all the calls to `alert()` but a kind of hook to that function which transforms it to `console.log()`

Comment: @Turnip aaah, that actually very simple and working! If you add that comment as a reply I mark it is an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
window.alert = window.console.log
window.alert('Hello from console.log')
```